# WebMethod return values in JSON format

Tags: asp.net, javascript, ajax, json

How to return values from Webmethod to the client in JSON format?

There are two static int values that i want to return.
Do I need to create new object with those 2 properties and return it?
The GetStatus() method is called frequently and i don't like the idea of creating a special object each time just for json formatting...

```
[WebMethod]
public static int GetStatus()
{
    int statusProcess,statusProcessTotal;

    Status.Lock.EnterReadLock();
    statusProcess=Status.Process; //Static field
    statusProcessTotal=Status.ProcessTotal; //Static field        
    Status.Lock.ExitReadLock();

    return ...
}
```

On client side I catch the return value in :

```
function OnSucceeded(result, userContext, methodName)   
(PageMethods.GetStatus(OnSucceeded, OnFailed);)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would just go with an object. It fits with what you need to do. If you have two return values you have to put them together in a structured way.

```
  public class StatusResult
        {
            public int StatusProcess { get; set; }
            public int StatusProcessTotal { get; set; }
        }

  [WebMethod]
        [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
        public StatusResult GetStatus()
        {
            int statusProcess,statusProcessTotal;

            //Status.Lock.EnterReadLock();
            statusProcess = 5;
            statusProcessTotal = 1; //Static field        


            var result = new StatusResult();
            result.StatusProcess = statusProcess;
            result.StatusProcessTotal = statusProcessTotal;

            return result;
        }
```

Comment: What about recreating new object every time the method is called? Doesn't it affect efficiency?

Comment: I've never had a problem. I think you are over thinking it.

Comment: It happens to the best of us.

Comment: I've voted you up :) . If there won't be any new answer i will accept yours.