# web service response and split it to more than one

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, json, web-services

i have a web service to fill html tags.

```
 [WebMethod]
 public string GetHelloMessage(string country)
 {
 string test = "<div>amin</div>";
 return test;
 }
```

and jquery is:

```
url: ServiceUrl,
type: "POST",
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
dataType: "jsonp",
timeout: 15000,
success: function (d) {
    if (d.length > 0) {
        var c = JSON.parse(d);
        if ($(".test1div").length) {
            $(".test1div").html(c.Content1)
        }if ($(".test2div").length) {
            $(".test2div").html(c.Content2)
        }
```

how to code web service to fill test2div tag ? how to add to return text from web service? example:

```
string Content1 = "<div>amin</div>";
string Content2 = "<div>reza</div>;
string Content3 = Content1 + Content2;
return Content3;
```

please help me with more explanation.

Comment: You should accept an answer and upvote when you solve your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Return a JSON object not just a string:

```
[WebMethod]
public string GetHelloMessage(string country)
{
    return "{ name : 'amin', surname : 'reza' }";
}
```

Then on the page do this:

```
var c = JSON.parse(d);

$(".test1div").html(c.name);
$(".test2div").html(c.surname);
```

Actually, the above code is an approximate answer.
You can try to deserialize twice:

```
JSON.parse((JSON.parse(d))
```

But sincerely, I doubt this is a good practice. Better leverage the internal mechanisms as explained in here: [WebMethod return values in JSON format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2127273/webmethod-return-values-in-json-format)

I don't know what the return value will be, but you can simply inspect it with `alert` or `console.log`.

Comment: What is the problem exactly? Obviously, you have to do adjust some other parts of your code, like the divs.

Comment: when add (var c = JSON.parse(d);) it doesn,t work. can you show me sample? when web service return one string it does work! but i want to fill 2 div tag.

Comment: should i change [webmethod]?

Comment: Sorry for the late response, I was offline. I've added a link and 2 lines of text, hope this helps a bit, otherwise I can't tell you much more than that without the actual program running in my hands...