# Expose data by a ASP.NET application

Tags: asp.net, web-services

I need your advice regarding exposing data from a web application A to be consumed by a web application B, both applications being ASP.NET WebForms application.

First thought I have in mind is to build a REST WCF webservice within web application A.

Is this the best option? What other options do I have with .NET 4.0?
Is Web API a better alternative? If yes, why?

**Later edit:**
I want to have call a method that receives 2 parameters and returns a class with 2 properties. In the future, I might need to add some similar methods.

**Later edit 2:**
The input parameters are sensitive, it there a way to send it someway so nobody can see them using a http proxy tool.

Comment: what do you want to do exactly? give some example for 'exposing' and 'consuming'
maybe you're looking for a simple web service?

Comment: @Visionstar: I've updated the initial post. Did I answer to your question?

Comment: If the data **is sensitive** then you have 2 options: server-side (client side has no access/visibility) or encryption if client is involved in any way. Depending on what you mean by "sensitive", _signing_ (instead of encrypting) is also an option.

Answer (score 1):

How about trying to implement a Webservice/webmethod?

I didnt exactly understand the purpose of transfering that data, but you can implement a webservice which passes a json-string

here is a example/tutorial of implementing web-methods:http://www.tutorialspoint.com/asp.net/asp.net_web_services.htm

also check out those two links:
[WebMethod return values in JSON format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2127273/webmethod-return-values-in-json-format)
[How do I make my aspx web method return the list as a JSON object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14079683/how-do-i-make-my-aspx-web-method-return-the-list-as-a-json-object)

Comment: Thanks for your response. As far I know, for a webservice, you need to have a proxy, or in other words, the application B should know implementation details about application A. Am I wrong?

Comment: You just have to know, that there is the webservice, which you can access via URL, that's all you need. If you want 2 different Applications to communicate with each other, then you will need something like this.

Comment: I see in your sample that a proxy should be created before consuming that web method...

Comment: Try this one: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/1d42da/web-service-basics/

I think that is what you need